# Draw a rectangle with a shadow on a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, shadow, rectangles

Currently, to draw a rectangle on my plot in matplotlib, I use:

```
currentAxis = plt.gca()
rect = mpatch.Rectangle((0.2, 0.420), 5.65, 0.730, edgecolor = None, facecolor = "white", zorder = 3)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect)
```

How to add a shadow to this rectangle (like for the legends) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once way of doing this is to use [transformations](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html).  Here is an example using the [scale translation](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.ScaledTranslation) method in an attempt to provide (I believe!) what you have asked for:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

# set up fig and axis
fig = plt.figure()
currentAxis = plt.gca()

# set translation 
dx, dy = 5/72., -5/72.
offset = transforms.ScaledTranslation(dx, dy, fig.dpi_scale_trans)
shadow_transform = currentAxis.transData + offset

# plot patch shadow
rect = patches.Rectangle((0.2, 0.420), 0.65, 0.730, transform=shadow_transform, 
                         edgecolor = None, facecolor = "black", zorder = 3)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect)

# plot patch
rect = patches.Rectangle((0.2, 0.420), 0.65, 0.730, edgecolor = None, 
                         facecolor = "white", zorder = 3)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect)
```

Note the `transform` argument passed to the `Rectangle` method.

output:

[image: shadowing]

Comment: pretty sure this very similar to the code used to do the drop shadow on fancy legend boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the built-in [shadow](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Shadow.html) in matplotlib

```
rect = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((0.4, 0.2), 0.4, 0.35, 
                                    facecolor='white', edgecolor='gray',
                                    transform=ax.transAxes)
shadow = matplotlib.patches.Shadow(rect, 1/72., -1/72)                                        
ax.add_patch(shadow)
ax.add_patch(rect)
```